# PHP: while loop elements sticking together

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

So I have an annoying issue with some of my code. I have been using a calendar code I found on WOWAwesome's youtube channel and using some PHP to be able to dynamically draw calendars using a function draw_calender() from this guy: https://davidwalsh.name/php-calendar

This is my code for generating each calendar:

```
    <?php  

     $sql2 = "SELECT timeStart, timeEnd, dateFor, languageTaught, status FROM tutorslots WHERE tutorid='$tutorid'";
        include('calendar/calendar.php');
            $result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);
                if (!$result2) {
                echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysqli_error();
                exit;
                }

             while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {

            $timeStart = $row2["timeStart"];
            $timeEnd = $row2["timeEnd"];
            $date = $row2["dateFor"];
            $languageTaught = $row2["languageTaught"];
            $status = $row2["status"];

            $dateElements = explode('-', $date);
            $year1 = $dateElements[0];
            $mo = $dateElements[1];
            $day1 = $dateElements[2];
            $lTaught1 = $languageTaught;

            echo "<h1>".$date."</h1>";
             echo "<br>";       
            echo draw_calendar($mo,$year1,$day1,$lTaught1);


             }
   ?>
```

here is the calendar.php page

```
   <html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device=width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

    <?php
    if(!function_exists('draw_calendar')){
        function draw_calendar($month,$year,$day1,$lTaught1){

            switch($lTaught1){
                    case "eng":
                        $language = "English";
                        break;
                    case "oth":
                        $language = "Other";
                        break;
                    case "chi":
                        $language = "Chinese";
                        break;
                };
            /* draw table */
            $calendar = '<div id="calendar-wrapper">';

            /* table headings */

            $calendar.= '<div id="weekday"><ul>
                <li>Sunday</li>
                <li>Moday</li>
                <li>Tuesday</li>
                <li>Wednesday</li>
                <li>Thursday</li>
                <li>Friday</li>
                <li>Saturday</li>
            </ul></div><div id="calendar">';

            /* days and weeks vars now ... */
            $running_day = date('w',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
            $days_in_month = date('t',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
            $days_in_this_week = 1;
            $day_counter = 0;
            $dates_array = array();

            /* row for week one */
            $calendar.= '<ul class="days">';

            /* print "blank" days until the first of the current week */
            for($x = 0; $x < $running_day; $x++):
                $calendar.= '<li class="day other-month"></li>';
                $days_in_this_week++;
            endfor;

            /* keep going with days.... */
            for($list_day = 1; $list_day <= $days_in_month; $list_day++):

                    /* add in the day number */
                    if($day1 == $list_day && $status="available"){
                         $calendar.= '<li class="day">';

                        $calendar .= '<div class="date">'.$list_day.'</div>';
                        $calendar .= '<div class="event">'.$language.'</div>';
                    } else {
                         $calendar.= '<li class="day">';
                    $calendar.= '<div class="date">'.$list_day.'</div>';
                    }


                $calendar.= '</li>';
                if($running_day == 6):
                    $calendar.= '</ul>';
                    if(($day_counter+1) != $days_in_month):
                        $calendar.= '<ul class="days">';
                    endif;
                    $running_day = -1;
                    $days_in_this_week = 0;
                endif;
                $days_in_this_week++; $running_day++; $day_counter++;
            endfor;

            /* finish the rest of the days in the week */
            if($days_in_this_week < 8):
                for($x = 1; $x <= (8 - $days_in_this_week); $x++):
                    $calendar.= '<li class="day other-month"></li>';
                endfor;
            endif;

            /* final row */
            $calendar.= '</ul>';

            /* end the table */
            $calendar.= '</div>';

            /* all done, return result */
            return $calendar;

        }
    }



?>


</body>
</html>
```

Sorry if this isn't formatted properly. Whats happening is this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCvV4.jpg my question is why isn't it going on a new line. When I tried to add jQuery tabs (there are three calendars that are generated) all of them went onto the first tabs div even though I had separated them.

Any help would be huge, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this belongs in a comment, but I can't until I have 50 rep, so here goes.

If you're wondering why your date is floating out to the right of your calendar, it's because it's not being drawn inside the draw_calendar() call.  You'll probably want it inside the #calendar-wrapper tag somewhere.

As for getting the calendars into jQuery tabs you'd have to provide the code you used for someone to have an opinion.